# When overriding DefaultStyleKey is necessary?

Tags: wpf, custom-controls

I have just spent like 2 hours trying to figure out why after moving a control from solution A to solution B (along with its style), the control stops showing up (control template was not applied). Turned out I forgot to override default style key. Here is the question: why did it work for solution A?

In DesignerView.cs:

```
 public class DesignerView : Control {
     // No DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata here
 }
```

In Generic.xaml:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type controls:DesignerView}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type controls:DesignerView}">
                <TextBlock Text="Hello" />
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Of course, my style is a little bit more complicated than that, but anyhow: exactly the same control (class+style, no proper DefaultStyleKeyProperty set) did show up in solution A, but didn't in solution B.

Comment: Could you show more, which control, an example of the working / non-working style?

Answer (score 11):

I guess you are talking about this:

```
    static MyControl()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(MyControl),
                     new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(MyControl)));
    }
```

Every control needs theme style which define its default template. (Most often for custom controls its defined under `Themes\Generic.xaml`).

**`DefaultStyleKeyProperty`** *defines the key used to find the theme style of the control*. If you comment out this line, it will pick default template of base class which generally is of type `Control`. (**But since `Control` does not have any default template defined for it, your control is not shown when you comment out this line**)

So, defaultStyleKeyProperty metadata needs to be overriden in static constructor ***to indicate that its default style is declared under Themes\Generic.xaml***.

If you change base class to say `Button` and you comment out this line, you will see it pick default template of Button class.

> So, for your question if your custom control is deriving from
>   Control, you need to override it to provide default template of control. In case deriving from control
>   whose default template is already defined then you can avoid
>   overriding it. It will pick base control style.

---

That being said for your question

> **why did it work for solution A?**

I suspect you have defined an explicit style somewhere in your
solution A which is missing from Solution B. And Solution B doesn't
have theme style set as well because of no override of metadata.

Comment: Yeah, I get it. And I even knew it. Thanks. But it does not answer the question, why style was working for solution A without overriding DefaultStyleKey. For all you said here, it should not have. (Yes, my control derives from System.Windows.Controls.Control)

Comment: `to indicate that its default style is declared under Themes\Generic.xaml`.
This bit is not true, though. DefaultStyleKey has little to do with Themes\Generic.xaml. I could just as fine compose the style in runtime and add it to the application's resource dictionary manually.

Comment: @Eugene - `DefaultStyleKey` is related to `Theme style` which is declared under `Themes\Generic.xaml`. `I could just as fine compose the style in runtime and add it to the application's resource dictionary manually.` - That's working because that's an explicit style and not Theme style. So, even if you don't override it and provide explicit style under App/Window/UserControl etc. it will pick that explicit style.

Comment: And for you question that `why it works for Solution A` - I suspect you have defined an explicit style somewhere in your solution A which is missing from Solution B. And Solution B doesn't have theme style set as well because of no override of metadata.

Comment: Hm.. Could you please clarify what is an "explicit style"? If you are referring to a style set via Style property, then it's not the case. And what is the difference between setting a style in Themes\Default.xaml and anywhere else (say, App.xaml)? I can't find any mention of Themes\Default.xaml in the documentation on DefaultStyleKey property. All it says that DefaultStyleKey is the key used to lookup a style for a control when no style is set explicitly.