# WPF custom template not displays buttons content

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, .net-6.0, .net-framework-version

I'm facing insidious bug which occurred during migration from .NET Framework 4.8 into .NET 6.0 in .NET WPF app.

Here is proper output displayed in .NET Framework:
[image]

And here is current .NET6.0 output result (Note missing buttons):
[image]

I would also add that the code remained unchanged during the migration from Framework to Core.
Can somebody PLEASE help and tell me why the buttons are not displayed as in previous example ?
Here is source code of these buttons:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type dialog:DialogTemplate}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Window}}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type dialog:DialogTemplate}">
                    <Grid Background="White">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition />
                            <RowDefinition Height="42" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <ContentPresenter Margin="10" />
                        <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Right" Grid.Row="1" Orientation="Horizontal"
                                    Margin="10">
                            <Button IsDefault="True" Command="dialog:DialogTemplate.DialogOKClickedCommand" Width="100" Margin="0,0,5,0" Content="{TemplateBinding OKButtonText}"  />
                            <Button IsCancel="True" Width="100">Abbrechen</Button>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

I tried to adjust ControlTemplate/ContentPresenter, but with no success.

Comment: I guess your Style is not actually applied.

Comment: Would you please have some more accurate information + how to fix ?

Comment: Recheck your Style is visible from your Window instance.

Comment: Are you sure that only the buttons are missing? I think the whole control template is not displayed. Change the background color of the "Grid" to something other than "White" to check this.

Comment: @LukášSrovnal: How do you apply the style to the window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your .NET6.0 custom control library project, you have to add a new file (if not present) "AssemblyInfo.cs" with the following content:

```
using System.Windows;

[assembly: ThemeInfo(
    ResourceDictionaryLocation.None,
    ResourceDictionaryLocation.SourceAssembly
)]
```

This file is generated automatically, if you create a custom control library in Visual Studio with target .NET6.0, but not with target .NET Framework 4.8.

For further informations see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.themeinfoattribute.-ctor?view=windowsdesktop-7.0&devlangs=csharp&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DDE-DE%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.ThemeInfoAttribute.%2523ctor)%3Bk(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue

Comment: Works as expected, MANY thanks, Andreas!

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you didn't override the DefaultStyleKey metadata. If you don't do this, your custom control (which derives from Window) will have a DefaultStyleKey = {x:Type Window}. So it won't find your style.

Check this: [When overriding DefaultStyleKey is necessary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21658599/when-overriding-defaultstylekey-is-necessary)

Btw, i advise you to use Snoop; with this you could see that the Style property of your custom window is not applied correctly, at least, that was the case in my code when i copied your code.

Comment: Hello, yes it's true, DefaultStyleKey metadata are commented, because without it, whole window is becoming black

Comment: Could you share the static constructor of your custom dialog? You hardcoded the background to white so it's weird that it becomes black..

Comment: ```static DialogTemplate()
        {
            //DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(DialogTemplate), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(DialogTemplate)));

            DialogOKClickedCommand = new RoutedUICommand("DialogOKClickedCommand", "DialogOKClickedCommand", typeof(DialogTemplate));
        }``` and the reason of black windows is supposedly WPF well known bug

Comment: I tried to reproduce the black window that you are getting, but to no avail. My guess is that you have to set AllowsTransparency to true for the DialogTemplate. Dialogs/popups have some dropshadow and for that this property has to be set to true. Just a guess, hopefully it works.